# Get the max value of dates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is my code and datetime columns.

```
import pandas as pd 
xcel_file=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',usecols=['datetime'])
date=[]
time=[]
date.append((xcel_file['datetime']).dt.date)
time.append((xcel_file['datetime']).dt.time)

new_file=pd.DataFrame({'a':len(xcel_file['datetime'])},index=xcel_file['datetime'])
day=new_file.between_time('9:00','16:00')
day.reset_index(inplace=True)
day=day.drop(columns={'a'})

day['time']=pd.to_datetime(day['datetime']).dt.date
model_list=day['time'].drop_duplicates()
data_set=[]
i=0
for n in day['datetime']:
    data_2=max(day['datetime'][day['time']==model_list[i])
    i+=1
    data_set.append(data_2)

datetime column
0  2022-01-10 09:30:00
1  2022-01-10 10:30:00
2  2022-01-11 10:30:00
3  2022-01-11 15:30:00
4  2022-01-11 11:00:00
5  2022-01-11 12:00:00
6  2022-01-12 13:00:00
7  2022-01-12 15:30:00
8  2022-01-13 14:00:00
9  2022-01-14 15:00:00
10 2022-01-14 16:00:00
11 2022-01-14 16:30:00

expected result
1  2022-01-10 10:30:00
3  2022-01-11 15:30:00
7  2022-01-12 15:30:00
8  2022-01-13 14:00:00
9  2022-01-14 15:00:00
```

I'm trying to get max value of same dates from datetime column in between time 9am to 4pm.
Is there any way of doing this? Truly thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question right. You have a dataframe with times and you'd like to get the max time in it in the range of 9am and 4pm?

Comment: Yes,I'm trying to get the max value of datetime of same dates in the range from 9to4.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) with aggregate by days in [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) for maximal datetimes:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',usecols=['datetime'])

df = df.set_index('datetime', drop=False)

df = (df.between_time('9:00','16:00')
        .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='d'))[['datetime']]
        .max()
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
             datetime
0 2022-01-10 10:30:00
1 2022-01-11 15:30:00
2 2022-01-12 15:30:00
3 2022-01-13 14:00:00
4 2022-01-14 16:00:00
```

EDIT: Added missing values if exist match, so [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) solve this problem.

```
print (df)
             datetime
0 2022-01-10 17:40:00
1 2022-01-10 19:30:00
2 2022-01-11 19:30:00
3 2022-01-11 15:30:00
4 2022-01-12 19:30:00
5 2022-01-12 15:30:00
6 2022-01-14 18:30:00
7 2022-01-14 16:30:00

df = df.set_index('datetime', drop=False)

df = (df.between_time('17:00','19:30')
        .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='d'))[['datetime']]
        .max()
        .dropna()
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
             datetime
0 2022-01-10 19:30:00
1 2022-01-11 19:30:00
2 2022-01-12 19:30:00
3 2022-01-14 18:30:00
```

Added alternative solution:

```
df = df.set_index('datetime', drop=False)

df = (df.between_time('17:00','19:30')
        .sort_index()
        .assign(d = lambda x: x['datetime'].dt.date)
        .drop_duplicates('d', keep='last')
        .drop('d', axis=1)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        )
print (df)
             datetime
0 2022-01-10 19:30:00
1 2022-01-11 19:30:00
2 2022-01-12 19:30:00
3 2022-01-14 18:30:00
```

EDIT: solution for filter first by `datetime` column, then `datetime2` and last filtering by `date`s from `datetime` column:

```
print (df)
             datetime           datetime2
0 2022-01-10 09:30:00 2022-01-10 17:40:00
1 2022-01-10 10:30:00 2022-01-10 19:30:00
2 2022-01-11 10:30:00 2022-01-11 19:30:00
3 2022-01-11 15:30:00 2022-01-11 15:30:00
4 2022-01-11 11:00:00 2022-01-12 15:30:00
5 2022-01-11 12:00:00 2022-01-14 18:30:00
6 2022-01-12 13:00:00 2022-01-14 16:30:00
7 2022-01-12 15:30:00 2022-01-14 17:30:00

df = (df.set_index('datetime', drop=False)
        .between_time('9:00','16:00')
        .sort_index()
        .set_index('datetime2', drop=False)
        .between_time('17:00','19:30')
        .assign(d = lambda x: x['datetime'].dt.date)
        .drop_duplicates('d', keep='last')
        .drop('d', axis=1)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        )
print (df)
             datetime           datetime2
0 2022-01-10 10:30:00 2022-01-10 19:30:00
1 2022-01-11 12:00:00 2022-01-14 18:30:00
2 2022-01-12 15:30:00 2022-01-14 17:30:00
```

If filtering by `date`s by `datetim2` output is different:

```
df = (df.set_index('datetime', drop=False)
        .between_time('9:00','16:00')
        .sort_index()
        .set_index('datetime2', drop=False)
        .between_time('17:00','19:30')
        .assign(d = lambda x: x['datetime2'].dt.date)
        .drop_duplicates('d', keep='last')
        .drop('d', axis=1)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        )
print (df)
             datetime           datetime2
0 2022-01-10 10:30:00 2022-01-10 19:30:00
1 2022-01-11 10:30:00 2022-01-11 19:30:00
2 2022-01-12 15:30:00 2022-01-14 17:30:00
```

Comment: @SajanShrestha - Do you think `4 2022-01-14 16:00:00` ?

Comment: @SajanShrestha If test `print (df.between_time('9:00','16:00'))` there are not datetimes between time 9am to 4pm ?

Comment: Thank you.I tried it but it also gives me the max value which doesn't belongs to the between time.  code:
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',usecols=['datetime','datetime2'])
df = df.set_index('datetime', drop=False)

df_ = (df.between_time('17:00','19:30')
        .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='d'))[['datetime','datetime2']]
        .max()
        .reset_index(drop=True))     results:             datetime           datetime2
2022-01-10 17:40:00 2022-01-10 19:30:00
2022-01-11 19:30:00 2022-01-11 15:30:00
2022-01-12 19:30:00 2022-01-12 15:30:00
2022-01-14 18:30:00 2022-01-14 16:30:00

Comment: @SajanShrestha - hmm, it is weird, for me working correct. Added to answer, also added alternative solution. Can you test both?

Comment: i tried this logic for more than one dataframe column which gives max value correctly but the time range isnot working for second column.

Comment: @SajanShrestha - hmmm, solution filter by index from `datetime` column, so is expected another column `datetime2` (which is not filtered) can contain values outside range.

Comment: Oh,I get it.Thank you.

Comment: @SajanShrestha - added solution for it, I hope working well.